# Python read a file returns a Python table

Tags: python

I am writing a function that reads into a file and returns a table as a nested list, all of the numbers are converted into integers.

This is how the file looks like:

```
a,a,1,a
4,a,a,a
a,a,a,2
a,3,a,a
```

This is my code:

```
def read_from_file(file_name):
    f=open(file_name, 'r')
    res = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(',')
        res.append(line)

    for i in range(len(res)):
        for j in range(len(res)):
            if res[i][j] == 'a\n':
                res[i][j] = 'a'
            if res[i][j] != 'a':
                res.append(int(res[i][j]))
    return res
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
[ [‘a’,‘a’,1,‘a’],
  [4,‘a’,‘a’,‘a’],
  [‘a’,‘a’,‘a’,2],
  [‘a’,3,‘a’,‘a’] ]
```

But when i run my code, errors happened:

```
res.append(int(res[i][j]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' a'
```

Any comment on what I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: ' x' can't be converted to an int, as your trying to do with `int(res[i][j])`

Comment: hi, thanks for your time, however, I wrote `if res[i][j] != 'x' ` means that if there is a number, ill convert it into integer

Comment: You have a space (' ') in there that's why it's not caught.  You may want to use `res[i][j].strip()`

Comment: it seems does not work after I used `strip()`, this error came up : `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: that's a separate error, you probably want to check the input data format, it may be missing a row or column

Comment: Cheers!!! thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another suggestion, but it will change the values inside processing list.

EDIT:

```py
def convert_int(file_name):
    astring = open(file_name, 'r').read()    # ' x,x,1,x\n4,x,x,x\nx,x,x,2\nx,3,x,x'
    alist = [y.split(",") for y in astring.split("\n")]  # [[' x', 'x', '1', 'x'], ['4', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', '2'], ['x', '3', 'x', 'x']]
    for asublist in alist:
        for i, x in enumerate(asublist):
            try:
               asublist[i] = int(x)
            except ValueError:
             pass
    return alist
```

```py
>>>convert_int(file_name)
[[' x', 'x', 1, 'x'], [4, 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 3, 'x', 'x']]
```

Comment: hi, the output is exactly what I wanted, so thank you. But is there any ways that I can write the function that take the `file_name` as the input? So I can read from different files? For example, `def convert_int(file_name)` ? as I dont want to change the input tho, I want it to be `file_name` thanks

Comment: One more thing with your code, the `a` in `for y in a.split("\n")]` is not define?

Comment: @Hannahpham, I edited as what you need, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you save the board in a file named `tmp`,

```
board = open('tmp', 'r').readlines()

def convert(item):
    tmp = []
    for piece in item.split(','):
        try:
            tmp.append(int(piece))
        except ValueError:
            tmp.append(piece.rstrip("\n"))
    return tmp

board = [convert(line) for line in board]

print(board)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your time. What if I want to read different files? as save the `board`, I can only read the file name `tmp` tho

Comment: `tmp` is just a random name of the file, you can save different boards to different files and process them using the pipeline in the answer

Comment: thank you. Just one more question, what is `item` in this case that user will input for the function `convert(item)` ? thanks again

Comment: you are welcome. `item` in this case is expected to be one line of the saved file (you can see this by playing with `open('tmp', 'r').readlines()`). It is accepted by `converter` to return a list with the expected format.